# PostgreSQL - WHERE clause within OVER clause?

Tags: postgresql

I need to use a where clause within an over clause. How?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) OVER(WHERE dateval > 12)
```

Or something like that.

--EDIT--

More details

My table is formatted with a year, month, and amount column.

I want to select all the year, month, and amount rows AND create a fourth 'virtual column' that has **the sum of the past 12 months of amount column.**

For example:

YEAR | MONTH | AMOUNT
2001 | 03 | 10
2001 | 05 | 25
2001 | 07 | 10

Should create:

YEAR | MONTH | AMOUNT | ROLLING 12 MONTHS
2001 | 03 | 10 | 10
2001 | 05 | 25 | 35
2001 | 07 | 10 | 45

Comment: Could you specify more accurately what you need, please?

Comment: Sure. I want to get the sum of ONLY rows where a certain column's value is less than 12, for example. I can't use the usual WHERE clause because I'm collecting some other stuff in the same query. So I need something like a WHERE clause, but within an OVER clause.

Comment: OK - thanks for the additional info - this looks much more like it would lend itself to window functions.  Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: I've edited my original answer to deal with the request in a windowed fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a query against your three-column resultset, does the below work for you?

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY YEAR ASC, MONTH ASC
                     ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
...
```

Comment: That's an aggregate function it won't work - let me update the OP with more details.

Comment: I guess we need to know what you're 'partitioning' by for this aggregate - if anything.

Comment: My pleasure.  Am looking forward to the next version of SQL Server so I can use this myself!  :)

Comment: @WillA just curious to know .what if the dates are not in the order. say if there are some missing months over a period of 12 months . how do we group it by months then. because 11 preceding might take dates from other years too.

Comment: @user2569524 Old question, but you'd just have to use PARTITION BY.  Something like `OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY MONTH ASC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`.  Don't need to ORDER BY YEAR anymore because there's only one year in each partition.  It might be preferable to say `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, since it should stop at the partition boundary.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a,(select sum(a) from foo fa where fa.a > fb.a) from foo fb;
```

Doesn't use over, is pretty inefficient since it is running new sub-query for each query, but it works.